# Determining the constant in the polytropic equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, astrophysics

Does the [polytropic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytrope)
$$
P=K\,\rho^\gamma
$$
hold for both constant and variable density and is there any analytical expression for constant $K$?

Also, for a particular layer of star, like inner crust or outer core, can we assign different values of $\gamma$? Or we may have to assign fixed value of $\gamma$ to obtained some specific solutions of equation of state.

Comment: Any time I've worked with the polytrope, it was assumed that $\rho$ is indeed a function of $r$--typically one uses this in the [stellar structure equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_structure#Equations_of_stellar_structure) to get, e.g., the Lane-Emden equation.

Comment: You can almost always define an equation of state similar to the one you have here if you really want to (i.e., fudge the constant and polytrope index enough to make things match observations) but whether it's physically meaningful is another question.